# Edit the first value in array everytime a new row has been pushed to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a string generator but I'm stuck on the last part.

I have an table with some input fields. This table can be cloned, so I don't know how many input fields there are, it could be 5, 10, 15, etc..

I'm using a function to loop through all input fields in the table. All those rows will be put together in 1 array. Then I'm using my`$(this).find(':input.generateinput').each` function to push those values into the array. The problem is that I need to add a string after the first value of every new row.

These are my results atm

1 row: `Window:1:200:0:1` needs to be: `Window:0:0.0000:1:200:0:1`

2 row: `Window:1:200:0:1,Door:1:100:0:2` needs to be: `Window:0:0.0000:1:200:0:1,Door:0:0.0000:1:100:0:2`

and so on..

As you can see the string that needs to be added is = `:0:0.0000`
And the `Window:1:200:0:1` is a string that has been put together by the values out of the array.

I hope you understand what I mean, if not feel free to ask me.

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
$('.generateString').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var arrayProducts = new Array();
  $('.tableProducts').each(function(i) {
    if (typeof arrayProducts[i] == "undefined")
      arrayProducts[i] = new Array();
    $(this).find(':input.generateinput').each(function(k) {
      // String that needs to be added behind every first item in a new array
      var string = ":0:0.0000";
      arrayProducts[i].push($(this).val());
      // Here comes the last part of the code I think
    });

  });
  var string = arrayProducts.join("|");
  var productstring = string.replace(/,/g, ":");

  var optionstring = arrayOptions.join("|");

  $('#optionstring').html(optionstring);
  $('#productstring').html(productstring.split(/:(?=\D)/g).toString());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productdiv">
  <table class="tableProducts">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>SKU:</td>
        <td>Default:</td>
        <td>Default Quantity:</td>
        <td>User defined:</td>
        <td>Position:</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="generateinput">
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="generateinput">
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="deleteProduct">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="addproduct">Add Option</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr class="hr">
<button class="generateString">Genereer string</button>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of arrays, or an array of strings? Your `Window:0:0.0000:1:200:0:1` example seems to be a string, but then in your JS you created nested arrays.

Comment: The Window:0:0.0000:1:200:0:1 is a string, but the values are from they array @nnnnnn

Comment: @mplungjan If your using that piece of, the string will be pushed behind every input, I only want it to be added behind every first item of a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `index==0` and add your custom string to that array value only. See below snippet and focus on the below statement,

```
arrayProducts[i].push($(this).val()+(k==0?string:''));// add string only for first indexed value
```

**Updated,** for the very first value you can distinguish it by a different class `custom` let say, like in the below code.

```
arrayProducts[i].push(this.value+($(this).hasClass('custom')?string:''));
```

```js
$('.generateString').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var arrayProducts = new Array();
  $('.tableProducts').each(function(i) {
    if (typeof arrayProducts[i] == "undefined")
      arrayProducts[i] = new Array();
    $(this).find('.generateinput').each(function(k) { // taking drop downs with input here
      // String that needs to be added behind every first item in a new array
      var string = ":0:0.0000";
      arrayProducts[i].push(this.value+($(this).hasClass('custom')?string:''));
      // Here comes the last part of the code I think
    });

  });
  var string = arrayProducts.join("|");
  var productstring = string.replace(/,/g, ":");

  var optionstring = arrayProducts.join("|");

  $('#optionstring').html(optionstring);
  $('#productstring').html(productstring.split(/:(?=\D)/g).toString());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productdiv">
  <table class="tableProducts">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>SKU:</td>
        <td>Default:</td>
        <td>Default Quantity:</td>
        <td>User defined:</td>
        <td>Position:</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput custom"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="generateinput">
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="generateinput">
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="generateinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="deleteProduct">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="addproduct">Add Option</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr class="hr">
<div id="optionstring"></div>
<div id="productstring"></div>
<button class="generateString">Genereer string</button>
```

Comment: That works only for the first index, but those rows are pasted in 1 array. I think I have explained the problem wrong. The array that will be created is something like this: ["Window", "1", "2", "0", "1", "Door", "1", "4", "0", "3"]. There are now 2 rows within this array.

Comment: @KoenvandeSande Its better to add a custom class to distinguish that value and to customise value for that input. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was the awsner that I was looking for. Thanks for the help bud!